# When should breadcrumbId be used?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Could you please give me some examples of usages of `breacrumbId` ? Also, what is the difference between `breadcrumbId` and `JMSMessageID`?

Comment: You can find some details about breadcrumb here: http://camel.apache.org/mdc-logging.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an ID used mainly by Apache Camel to track a message through different transports. So, that same breadcrumbId can be propagated to HTTP headers or whatnot to keep track of the message. When only using ActiveMQ in isolation, you may not have much use of breadcrumbId.